# Laravel array data get in blade its show only one

Tags: php, laravel

**my controller**

```
 foreach($tracks as $key => $track){
                $singers =Singers::whereIn('id',$track->singers_id)->pluck('singers_name')->toarray();
                dump($singers);
            }
```

**my blade**

```
{{implode(' & ', $singers)}}
```

**my data**

```
^ array:2 [▼
  0 => "Norman"
   1 => "vicky"
]

^ array:2 [▼
  0 => "Ella Mai"
  1 => "vicky"
]
```

1-In controller get  all data working fine but am showing in blade its show only last record.

2-And same singer name show only once how here vicky show two times

Comment: You should take all the singers in array and then directly put that array to whereIn function;

Answer (score 0):

Here you overwrite $singers in the loop, so you end with the latest one:

```
 foreach($tracks as $key => $track){
                $singers =Singers::whereIn('id',$track->singers_id)->pluck('singers_name')->toarray();
                dump($singers);
            }
```

You can do so to have to store them all in an array:

```
 foreach($tracks as $key => $track){
                $singers[] = Singers::whereIn('id',$track->singers_id)->pluck('singers_name')->toarray();
            }
```